# PHP DateTime: 'previous week' or 'last week'?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the date of the first day of the last week:

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake')); 
$date = $date->modify('previous week');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

and

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Wake')); 
$date = $date->modify('last week');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Both work.
But is there any difference?

Comment: No, there is no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same, you can confirm this for yourself if you want, the PHP source code is available on github.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1443

```
PHP_FUNCTION(strtotime)
{
    ...
    t = timelib_strtotime(initial_ts, strlen(initial_ts), NULL, DATE_TIMEZONEDB, php_date_parse_tzfile_wrapper); /* we ignore the error here, as this should never fail */
```

So it calls `timelib_strtotime`, where can this be found? Well luckily that's online too

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L24743

```
timelib_time* timelib_strtotime(char *s, int len, struct timelib_error_container **errors, const timelib_tzdb *tzdb, timelib_tz_get_wrapper tz_get_wrapper)
{
    ...
    do {
        t = scan(&in, tz_get_wrapper);
#ifdef DEBUG_PARSER
            printf("%d\n", t);
#endif
    } while(t != EOI);
    ...
```

Which relies on `scan`:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L835

```
static int scan(Scanner *s, timelib_tz_get_wrapper tz_get_wrapper)
{
     ...
     while(*ptr) {
         i = timelib_get_relative_text((char **) &ptr, &behavior);
```

Which makes a call to `timelib_get_relative_text`

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L561

```
static timelib_sll timelib_get_relative_text(char **ptr, int *behavior)
{
    while (**ptr == ' ' || **ptr == '\t' || **ptr == '-' || **ptr == '/') {
        ++*ptr;
    }
    return timelib_lookup_relative_text(ptr, behavior);
}
```

Which makes a call to `timelib_lookup_relative_text`:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L536

```
static timelib_sll timelib_lookup_relative_text(char **ptr, int *behavior)
{
    ...
    for (tp = timelib_reltext_lookup; tp->name; tp++) {
        if (strcasecmp(word, tp->name) == 0) {
            value = tp->value;
            *behavior = tp->type;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Which in turn uses a structure set called `timelib_reltext_lookup` defined at the top of the file:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L248

```
  static timelib_lookup_table const timelib_reltext_lookup[] = {
     { "first",    0,  1 },
     { "next",     0,  1 },
     { "second",   0,  2 },
     { "third",    0,  3 },
     { "fourth",   0,  4 },
     { "fifth",    0,  5 },
     { "sixth",    0,  6 },
     { "seventh",  0,  7 },
     { "eight",    0,  8 },
     { "eighth",   0,  8 },
     { "ninth",    0,  9 },
     { "tenth",    0, 10 },
     { "eleventh", 0, 11 },
     { "twelfth",  0, 12 },
     { "last",     0, -1 },
     { "previous", 0, -1 },
     { "this",     1,  0 },
     { NULL,       1,  0 }
  };
```

Hopefully this is sufficient proof that they are, in every way, the same.

Answer (score 1):

The word "previous" is supported since PHP5, "last" since PHP4. The result of both is the same and both are still valid.